# Scrollable Recyclerview Horizontal and Vertical Landscape

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When I use the ScrollView and HorizontalScrollView to make both horizontal and vertical scrolling possible and switch to landscape, RecyclerView does not fill the screen like in portrait orientation.

I am using relative widths of elements in one row layout and everything looks good in portrait orientation.

Fragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/table_border">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/tableView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            tools:listitem="@layout/table_inventory_row"
            />
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</ScrollView>
```

One row layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtId"
        android:layout_weight=".15"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:text="@string/id"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtManager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:text="@string/manager"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCreatedDate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:text="@string/created_on"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtExecutionDate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:text="@string/executed_on"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDone"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:text="@string/is_done"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

```java
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                    from(parent.getContext()).
                    inflate(R.layout.table_inventory_row, parent, false);
            return new RowViewHolder(itemView);

    }
```

Landscape https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGfI9.jpg

Portrait https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J9JH.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Kiib.jpg

As you can see in the screenshot I have put blue border to Horizontal scroller and it takes the whole screen but RecyclerView does not match the width.

How can I make RecyclerView to take the full width of the parent?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is how you create each row. You are getting exactly what you are requesting. The rows are all the same size. When you are in portrait mode, your recycler view is larger than the screen width. However, in landscape mode, your row is the exact same size, but it doesn't cover the entire screen width.

What you should do is use `wrap_content` on your text view widths, rather than setting the weight. When you set the weight, you are creating a static size. Using the `wrap_content` you will wrap all your content.

Also, in your fragment, make sure that you are creating a new instance of your views when you rotate by doing:

```
Fragment.setRetainInstance(false);
```

Comment: I thought of that but I am trying to make a table, if I do so mine columns won't be of the same width. But still, I don't  understand why recycler view wraps the content instead of matching the parent in width?

Comment: Can you post your fragment code? You could also set a min width on the elements.

Answer (score 1):

First Prepare your **RecyclerView** layout as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite">
....

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation" />

        </HorizontalScrollView>

 .....


</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, Add

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

to your **Manifests.xml**

That's all setup your recyclerview from activity/fragment.

For more details, Here's an [Article](https://medium.com/@iamnaran/horizontal-vertical-scrolling-in-recyclerview-4a164296ef63) for you.